# How to fix broken dependencies, that require deinstalling dnf on Fedora 23?

Tags: fedora, package-management, upgrade, dependencies, dnf

I've recently upgraded from Fedora 21 right up to Fedora 23.
Most things went down without much drama (including nVidia drivers), except for the packages involving `dnf`.

After upgrading, performing a `dnf upgrade` gives me this:

```
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 sqlite                      x86_64                      3.11.0-1.fc23                       updates                      484 k
```

An `rpm -qa | grep sqlite` informs me of another version of sqlite currently being installed:

```
sqlite-3.10.2-1.fc23.x86_64
```

Now, I thought I could quickly resolve that with using `dnf upgrade --best --allowerasing`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work this time, because a prior version is installed already:

```
Error: cannot install both sqlite-3.11.0-1.fc23.x86_64 and sqlite-3.10.2-1.fc23.x86_64
```

I thought I might simply uninstall the sqlite package, remove dependent packages, install the newer version of sqlite, and then install the dependent packages. This obviously takes a bit of time, but it's what I was already used to do. Kindof a manual dependency resolution if you like.

However, `dnf remove sqlite` gives me this:

```
Error: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: systemd, dnf.
```

So, how do I go from this point on? I obviously can't uninstall `dnf`, or `systemd` as such. Is there a way I can force the upgrade of a package that is a dependency of other packages, which are blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue with sqlite is a transient problem with a bad update that made it to the repositories. (Negative QA feedback came in too late after several testers had already given it the go-ahead.) There is a [newer update in testing](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2016-850f410498) which should fix the issue.

That should address your immediate problem; I'm not sure if you need a more general answer or not — unfortunately, I think the general answer is often "well, you can't, really... when the update repository is in an incoherent state, there's not much to be done." If you *really* want to dig into it (if, for example, a serious security issue were at stake), you could bypass DNF and just use rpm directly (at least until the problem is in a dependency of RPM itself).

Comment: I was considering uninstalling the 3.10 version and shoving the 3.11 version "under the feet" of the dependent packages, but I'm a little afraid I might break things, especially since the repo db would be changed without being notified of these changes. Also, I'm not quite sure if `dnf` and `systemd` will work with the never version of sqlite.

Comment: So, I take it, the only reasonable thing to do now, is to just wait and see?

Comment: @polemon Well, I see that the newer update I linked is currently at +2, and has a threshold of +3 for being pushed to stable. You could `dnf --enablerepo=updates-testing upgrade sqlite`, and then ensure that everything still works, and then provide the missing additional +1. Or, yeah, you could wait for someone else to do that. (Or, if no one does, the package maintainer will be able to push it anyway after two weeks.)

Comment: More on updates-testing and QA feedback at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Updates_Testing

Comment: I ended up simply waiting for the packages to be fixed.